# How to install libsecp256k1 to a custom location in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, installation

I already know to install libsecp256k1 to standard location by cloniong from https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1. Such as

```
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make check  # run the test suite
$ sudo make install  # optional
```

But I could not locate and reference about installing libsecp256k1 to a custom location like /usr/local/ in Ubuntu?

Comment: Default install destination *is* `/usr/local/` , which will know when omitting sudo : `make install` → →  `/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/lib/libsecp256k1.so.0.0.0': Permission denied` . ........... Options : `$ ./configure --help`

Answer (score 0):

Run `./configure --help` to see what other options you have.
To install in another location you could, for instance, run:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/third_party/secp256k1
make
make install
```